# Date change issue in struts2

Tags: java, date, struts2, datepicker

When i  selecting the date format from date picker it showing in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.
 Passing the date into java class it become "MM/dd/yyyy".
 Due to this reason i can't pass the day above 12 ,it showing input error.

Example: 11/08/2014 in jsp the same date showing in
 java class is Sat Nov 08 00:00:00 IST  2014

Comment: Search Stackoverflow for "Java date" to find hundreds of examples dealing with parsing date strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateFormat to convert the date in the desired format.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String currDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Actually its working perfectly except one of the computer.All are added same library.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Date conversion in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20641525/1654265), then set a Locale to Struts2 in struts.xml in the following way:

```xml
<constant name="struts.locale" value="it_IT"  />
```

with your desired Locale instead of `it_IT`, if you are not building a multi-language (i18n) web application.

Also consider using HTML5 native `<input type="date" />`, with a fallback (in this case with Modernizr) to jQuery for browsers not supporting that feature:

```
<script>
    // If not native HTML5 support, fallback to jQuery datePicker
    $(function(){
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                // Consistent format with the HTML5 picker
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                },
                // Localization
                $.datepicker.regional['it']
            );
        }
    });
</script>
```