# Aligning data in JSP while using struts2

Tags: struts2

While using `struts2` tags I wrote `jsp` as

```
<s:textfield        name="NumOfSeats"       label="No. of Berths"/>
<sx:datetimepicker  name="date"             label="Date of journey"     displayFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" />
<s:textfield        name="trainNo"          label="Train no"/>
```

I got my page like this(Lables and textfilelds at same height)

[image: Lables and textfilelds at same height]

As I need datetimepicker I added this `<sx:head></sx:head>`. Then page became like this(label and text field at different heights)

[image: label and text field at different heights]

What can I do for making them to align at same height.

Comment: S2 dojo plugin is deprecated.

Comment: Then how can I add _datetimepicker_ in my form

Comment: The easiest way ? Use struts2-jquery plugin's autocompleter. The better way ? Use HTML5's <Input type="date"/>, with a fallback in jQuery (either raw jQuery or struts2-jquery plugin). Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28581773/1654265

Comment: I mean datetimepicker, not autocompleter :P

Comment: I am going through it

Comment: There is also a sample code for a jQuery fallback: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27224716/1654265 feel free to upvote if it helps