# While posting a from with date field is not being converted properly in Java

Tags: java, jquery, date, struts2

Java + Struts2 
Scenario: A web page with search having from and to date which uses Jquery datepicker(mm/dd/yy). When using this web page from Desktop/Laptop the date conversion from date field to java Date object is working fine. 
Means when posting a date "01/12/2016" in java Date object i get "12th january 2016" but when using it from mobile device date object in Java will show "1st December 2016".

Is there any configuration parameter which i need to set in struts ?

Comment: This screams localisation. But you need to add some of the code, that we can help yo out.

Comment: See [Is it possible to configure unified format of date format for whole struts webapp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23084580/573032)

Comment: Yes it was problem with localisation. Struts convert String to Date based on device local. Now I have overridden struts type conversion for Date and it works perfect for my scenario. https://struts.apache.org/docs/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [how Struts2 handles date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20641525/1654265).

You can specify the locale server side and the `dateFormat` client side, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27224716/1654265).

You should also consider [using the native HTML5 datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30503903/1654265), very important for mobile browsing.

If using RFC3339 dates, however, remember to create a simple converter, or [wait for Struts 2.3.25](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4551).